# How do I distinguish women cloth from men cloth?

Tags: clothing, fatwa

In a fatwa about women wearing pants,I read that it is permissible for women to wear pants if it is loose & not similar to pants that men wear. But I'm having a hard time understanding what kind of pants are for women. I mean men wear all kinds of pants these days. Can I buy a pair of pants from a shop if it says "Women trousers" on the lebel? Will that lebel be enough for me to explain myself to allah? Usually where I come from, people especially my moms age tend to consider pants as men clothing.however modern muslim women are seen wearing pants in recent times.

Comment: Clothes of either gender are commonly known and can be differentiated easily.

Comment: Try wearing abaya in nordic countries where gusts are common. With blustery winds being so STRONG, you would really need EIGHT ARMS to hold down the hem of your abaya. Otherwise, gusty winds can compromise your modesty, whereas trousers (US equivalent for pants) saves your embarrassment.

Comment: @RitaGeraghty I don't see how this comment is relevant and I wonder if it is kind offending (See [our code of conduct](https://islam.stackexchange.com/conduct)).

Comment: It's a little complicated here in bangladesh. Older people tend to consider trousers as men clothing beacuase trousers aren't traditional garment for women but men. My mom forbids me to wear them because the shariah says that men and women clothing should be different @Medi1Saif

Comment: @nowrinafrin, you wear what is expected in your country, what traditions demand. In nordic countries, Muslims wear their clothes little differently. They wear whatever clothes that are practical for worst weathers like blizzards, rainstorm, etc. Otherwise, they can catch frostbites, chilblains, pneumonia, etc.